# Monitor movement on a real world track controls Unity Camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am working, or about to be working, on a project where I would like to move a monitor along a railed track, left to right and vice versa, and have the camera in Unity update its movement left or right to follow the track movement. I am attempting to do something like this [Video Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_aZM8uupYE) but on a smaller scale, and have, at certain points along the track, triggers that will spawn different animations based on where on the track the monitor is, sort of like a timeline.

I guess my question is, does anyone have any thoughts or ideas on how this is accomplished? My initial thought is using a accelerometer to get movement data and use that with some scripting to control the camera, but I am not sure how big a factor the potential error may be with this approach. Another idea would be to use some sort of Laser Range Finder to get a constant distance strapped to the back of the monitor or the track, right now I am really just brainstorming.

On the unity side of things I will be fine, I am just wondering if there are other ways, or if people may have other ideas on how this is done, before I jump into spending money on trial and error modes. Thanks for any insight that anyone may be able to offer in advanced!

Comment: I am a bit confused. By monitor you mean an **actual** monitor? You will move it in real world, and display something on its screen according to movement of the monitor ?

Comment: how do you plan to move the monitor? if its tracked with wheels you could also use a rotary encoder, its probably a lot cheaper than a laser rangefinder. but this thread is kinda offtopic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Right, the monitor will be on a track in the real world. Sorry if the thread is a bit off topic, I was not sure where to go to for ideas. I will look into rotary encoders. Thanks.